# Unexpected at this time

Tags: cmd, teamcity

I have a command line build runner in Teamcity that runs the following custom script:

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /ad /b "D:\CRC Releases"') do @rd /q /s "D:\CRC Releases\%%i"
```

However I get the following error:

```
\CRC was unexpected at this time
```

Is there anything wrong with the syntax of the script? Please note that when I trigger this directly via the command prompt (with single %) it works just fine. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Since a command is being run, I would use backticks and use () around the DO command portion. `FOR /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i IN (\`dir /ad /b "D:\CRC Releases"\`) do (@rd /q /s "D:\CRC Releases\%%~i")` What happens with that?

Comment: I received this error: `The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter substitution is invalid: %~i")`

Comment: Have you tried with single `%` in Teamcity?

Comment: The `dir` will probably give a full pathname. Use only the variable. `FOR /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i IN (``dir /ad /b "D:\CRC Releases"``) do (@rd /q /s "%%~i")`

Comment: @lit: no, the `dir` will only give subfolder names (as there is no `/s`) . To get the full path, use `for /f  %a in ('dir /ad /b "d:\CRC Releases"') do @echo %~fa`

Comment: @Stephan - Thanks. The /S slipped my mind.

Comment: @lit: The error still persists. Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: remove the `@` to see the executed line (or add an `ECHO` before). What does it say?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it on my machine. I am sorry, but I do not get the same result. It appears to work as expected on my system.

Comment: same thing here: seems to work fine.

Comment: @Stephan, using the `~f` modifier is nice, but may lead to trouble here, because it refers to the *current working directory*, which may not necessarily be `D:\CRC Releases`; I'd use `cd /D` or `pushd` to change to `D:\CRC Releases` in advance, then I'd use `dir /B /A:D` without any path and `~f`...

Comment: The code as you posted does not contain any syntax error. What is the encoding of the script - ASCII/ANSI, or Unicode? what line-breaks does it contain (Windows-/Mac-/Unix-style)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the forementioned script is really not working so I decided to use the script below instead:

```
FOR /D %%p IN ("D:\CRC Releases\*.*") DO rmdir "%%p" /s /q
```

I triggered this as an executable file in Teamcity and it did the job. Thank you for everyone who helped me with this issue.

Comment: You should state `rmdir "%%~p" /s /q` (note the `~`) to avoid trouble in case some special characters occur...

Comment: Special characters in the file name?

Comment: Something like `&` or `^`, for example, which both have special meaning to `cmd`; your syntax `"%%p"` actually double-quotes the directory path , like `""D:\Releases\sample-dir""`, so the path appears unquoted; using `"%%~p"` lets it expand to `"D:\Releases\sample-dir"`, so the path appears properly quoted, hence characters like `&` or `^` cannot harm...